# Get specific value from Object in PHP

Tags: php, string, object

```
<?php

$a['registrationID']="*******";
$a['password']="******";
$a['smsPort']=7424;
$a['msgID']=0;

$soap_url='http://localhost/WebService_GP_ADP_BizTalk_SMS_Orchestrations.wsdl';
$soap = new SoapClient($soap_url);

$response=$soap->getReceivedSMS( array ("ReceiveSMSRequest" => $a) );
print_r($response);
?>
```

---

This returns:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ReceiveSMSResponse] => stdClass Object
        (
            [msgID] => 20100620202512840316
            [senderMSISDN] => 1732172782
            [timeStamp] => 6/20/2010 8:25:14 PM
            [msgContent] => testing
            [sourcePort] => 7424
        )

)
```

How do I get the different parts of the object and put them separately into strings?
e.g. i want something like $msgcontent= //whatever is in  [msgcontent]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `->` operator. In your specific example:

```
print($response->ReceiveSMSResponse->msgContent);
```

For more information, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Thanks a lot i was getting mad this was a very clear question with the perfect answer